# Regarding DataFrame Split

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to know how to split DataFrame Data automatically
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVZnY.png)

First, I want to split each 10 row data, so it can be made approximately 370 dataframe.

Second, I want to assingn 370 dataframe to variables.

Eventually, i want to proceed with the above processes at once, by using for codes.

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), put the code in the question itself. Take a look at the help guides on [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and more specifically, please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for an horizontal split.
If you want to split your data at the index p, you use:
 df1,df2=df.iloc[:p].copy(),df.iloc[p:].copy()

If you are looking for a random split you can you scikit function:

sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split